# LyX: Change paragraph style without affecting nested styles?

Tags: lyx

In LyX, some environments are handled by "Paragraph styles", and nested environments are handled by allowing to "indent" a paragraph to signal that it should be contained inside the environment of the previous paragraph.

[image]

In pseudocode (in case the image becomes inaccessible):

```
== LyX ==                == LaTeX ==
[Style: Quote] Hello.    \begin{quote}
[Style: Itemize] Wide.       Hello
[Style: Quote] World.    \end{quote}
                         \begin{itemize}
                             \item Wide.
                         \end{itemize}
                         \begin{quote}
                             World.
                         \end{quote}
```

as opposed to

```
== LyX ==                    == LaTeX ==
[Style: Quote] Hello.        \begin{quote}
    [Style: Itemize] Wide.       Hello.
[Style: Quote] World.            \begin{itemize}
                                     \item Wide.
                                 \end{itemize}
                                 World.
                             \end{quote}
```

---

I have some cases, where the outer environment is rather long (upward of a dozen of paragraphs) containing several such nested environments. I want to dissolve the outer environment (in LyX term: Paragraph style "Standard"), but if I just mark the whole reqgion and select "Standard", the nested Styles are lost, e.g.

[image]

```
== LyX Before ==                         == LyX After ==
[Style: Quote] Hello.       "Standard"   [Style: Standard] Hello.
    [Style: Itemize] Wide.     --->      [Style: Standard] Wide.
[Style: Quote] World.                    [Style: Standard] World.
```

The (inconvenient) alternative is to change each "Quote" styled paragraph separately. In this example it would be simple; In real world examples it may involve changing dozens of paragraphs.

Is there any more efficient way to change the Style of a sequence of paragraphs without changing the style of the nested paragraphs?

### Example document (save as `document.lyx`)

```
#LyX 2.3 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 544
\begin_document
\begin_header
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Quote
Hello.
\end_layout

\begin_deeper
\begin_layout Itemize
Wide.
\end_layout

\end_deeper
\begin_layout Quote
World.
\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

### Specific usecase

I am using a view environments for editorial markup, e.g. `continue` for sections and paragraphs, that need to be finished yet. Since LyX "Flex Insets" are ill-equipped for handling multi-paragraph contents, I prefer translating these into styles (as LocalLayout or custom module) such as

```
Style Continue
  Category    Editorial
  LatexType   environment
  LatexName   continue
  LabelString "Continue."
  LabelType   static
  LabelSep    x
  Margin      first_dynamic
End
```

The usability issue occurs when trying to mark the contents as "Done" by removing the "continue" wrapper.